# Is there a SQL Server 2008 R2 specific target for SSDT projects?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-clr

I am making a SQLCLR stored procedure in Visual Studio 2012. I have these options for target platform:

[image: SSDT platforms sql server 2005, 2008,. 2012, Azure]

Is there not a SQL Server 2008 R2 specific option? Is this because SQL 2008 R2 shares the same [compatibility level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) of 100 with SQL Server 2008?

Comment: I believe it's because there weren't any major changes in terms of SQLCLR from 2008 to 2008 R2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 2008 and 2008R2 user database is schema compatible, hence one version for both in SSDT. In other words, there aren't any schema objects that you could add to a 2008R2 SSDT model that couldn't be created in 2008.

This isn't the same as either [database version or database compatibility level](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-13-difference-between-database-version-and-database-compatibility-level/).

Database version:

> The database version is a number stamped in the boot page of a
>   database that indicates the SQL Server version of the most recent SQL
>   Server instance the database was attached to. The database version
>   number does not equal the SQL Server version.

Database compatibility level:

> The database compatibility level determines how certain database
>   behaviors work. For instance, in 90 compatibility, you need to use the
>   OUTER JOIN syntax to do an outer join, whereas in earlier
>   compatibility levels, you can use `*=` and `=*`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not just the compatibility level. Also the .NET options themselves are the same against both 2008 and 2008 R2.

In a word:

> > Is there not a SQL Server 2008 R2 specific option?

No

> > Is this because SQL 2008 R2 shares the same compatibility 
> >     level of 100 with SQL Server 2008?

Not exactly, but it doesn't really matter.